# Android studio Relative Layout click and go to another form - java

Tags: java, android

I have a relative layout with an image and 2 texts. I need when the user presses the relative layout to go to another activity and show those texts and image in a bigger format. Is this possible? If yes how i do this?
This is what i have done:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/piUjZ.png

Comment: Be familiar with android and java before start coding....!!!!! *_*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible.

Just add [OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) to your relative layout, and pass Intent to next activity.

1 - Give your RelativeLayout an ID

2 - Set your `RelativeLayout` XML to `android:clickable="true"`

Your final xml will be look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutTest"
android:clickable="true">
```

3 - Then add the code in your onCreate method :

```
RelativeLayout relative1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutTest);
  relative1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
         //you can pass image & text over here using putExtra()
        startActivity(new Intent(this, YOURCLASS.class) );
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is what i need. By "YOUR CLASS.class" you mean the second activity that i need to go? i mean the second java class that refers to the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.
Take bigger TextView and ImageView and set visibility gone by default.
Set onClickListener on Relative Layout by findViewById
and onClick of RelativeLayout turn visibility on of both views and make gone visibility of smaller views.

Answer (score 0):

set relativelayout click listener and pass all these three using

```
intent.putExtra("name",name[postion]);
intent.putExtra("name",image[postion]);
intent.putExtra("name",text[postion]);
```

and get these into your second activity and show where you want to show